# Get unread Mails from Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Is there any way to get all mail from an specific Folder into my Application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301882/reading-email-without-outlook-app-open). [Introduction to Outlook Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167(VS.71).aspx) will explain things more clearly.

You could loop through the mailitems. Sample code

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

    OutLook.Application oApp;
             OutLook._NameSpace oNS;
             OutLook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
             OutLook._Explorer oExp;

             oApp = new OutLook.Application();
             oNS = (OutLook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
             oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OutLook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
             oExp = oFolder.GetExplorer(false);
             oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

        OutLook.Items items = oFolder.Items;
        foreach (OutLook.MailItem mail in items)
                        {

                            if (mail.UnRead == true)
                            {
                        }
        }
```

Edit:
[Reference other folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310244)

```
oFolder.Folders["Foldername"]
```

[OutLook Code](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=40)

[Common Outlook tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268731(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Yeah thats what i want! Thanks, but is there a way to get the Items of the Inbox from another Mailbox wich is in Outlook?

Comment: Looping through all items in a folder is a terrible idea, especially if you are working against an online Exchange store. Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Looping through all items in a folder is a terrible idea, especially if you are working against an online Exchange store. `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` is the way to go.

Find/FindNext:

```
OutLook.Items items = oFolder.Items;
OutLook.MailItem mail = items.Find("[Unread] = true");
while (mail != null)
{
  MessageBox.Show(mail.Subject);
  mail = items.FindNext();
}
```

Items.Restrict:

```
OutLook.Items items = oFolder.Items.Restict("[Unread] = true")
foreach (OutLook.MailItem mail in items)
{
  MessageBox.Show(mail.Subject);
}
```

Comment: What is the filter for retrieving emails from yesterday ? I've tried this
     

    [SentOn] > '5/17/2017 4:21:33 PM' But it doesn't seem to work. It is returning zero records

Comment: Either that or [ReceivedTime].

Comment: Yes I was making a small mistake in  formatting the date. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's some examples of accessing Outlook folders [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3894), one of which deals specifically with unread mail.

Edit: There's a KB article specifically about accessing folders from C#, [Programming samples that can reference items and folders in Outlook by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310244)

To open another user's folder, use [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220116%28office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (Object Unreadmail in folderItems)
            {
                if ((Unreadmail as Outlook.MailItem) != null && (Unreadmail as Outlook.MailItem).UnRead == true)
                {
                  //DO Your action Here
                }
            }
```

I have experienced "COM_object" exception error with above solutions, More info please refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656360/unable-to-cast-com-object-microsoft-outlook-c-sharp)