# Save outlook sent mail folder in sql

Tags: c#, outlook, casting, com-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to save out sent mail folder data in sql however I'm getting cast com object of type error/ I tried to online repair the Microsoft app and nothing happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection; // to use Missing.Value
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace RetrieveEmail
{
    public class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application oLk = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._NameSpace olNS = oLk.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolderIn = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);



            Outlook.Items oItems = oFolderIn.Items;

            foreach (Outlook.MailItem oMailItem in oFolderIn.Items)
            {
                if (oMailItem.SenderName != null)
                {

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=EmailReply;Integrated Security=True");
                 
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Emails (SenderName, Subject, Body) VALUES (@SenderName, @Subject, @Body)", con);
                    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderName", oMailItem.SenderName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", oMailItem.Subject);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", oMailItem.Body);
                    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Open();
                    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (k != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Record Inserted Succesfully into the Database");

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast COM object - Microsoft outlook & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656360/unable-to-cast-com-object-microsoft-outlook-c-sharp)

Comment: No i didn't answer I need MailItem to save in SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have item types other than `MailItem` in the Sent Items folder - most likely you also have `MeetingItem` objects.

```
foreach (object item in oFolderIn.Items)
{
  if (item is Outlook.MailItem oMailItem)
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it however right now I'm trying to extract attachment files from outlook save in sql, any idea?

Comment: Loop through the Attachments collection, and call Attachment.SaveAsFile for each attachment. You can then insert the file into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook allows placing different kind if items into a folder. So, each time you iterate over all items you need to check the underlying type by using the is operator in C#:

```
foreach (object item in oFolderIn.Items)
{
   if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
   {
       // cast item to MailItem.
       Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
       // your code here for the mailItem object
   }
   if (item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
   {
       // cast item to MeetingItem.
       Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem = item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
       // your code here for the meetingItem object

   }
}
```

So, first of all, you need to define a loop which uses as object instead of a mail item, so you could iterate over all items in the folder. Then you need to check the underlying type of the object.

Note, if you need to process other item types in Outlook you need to add similar checks for each item type.