# Get all mails in outlook from a specific folder

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I would like to get all mails in outlook from a specific folder:

My folder structure:

[image: My folder structure]

I find this [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055811/get-unread-mails-from-outlook) to get all mails in outlook inbox folder (not the inbox in picture!):

```
Outlook.Application oApp;
Outlook._NameSpace oNS;
Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
Outlook._Explorer oExp;

oApp = new Outlook.Application();
oNS = (Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
oExp = oFolder.GetExplorer(false);
oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

Outlook.Items items = oFolder.Items;
foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in items)
{
    //do someting
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get all mails from a specific folder (like: wolfy-server)?

Answer (score 2):

This should work!!!

```
MAPIFolder mailsFromThisFolder;

MAPIFolder mainFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

foreach (MAPIFolder folder in mainFolder.Folders)
{
    GetFolders(folder);
}

public void GetFolders(MAPIFolder folder)
{
    if (folder.Folders.Count == 0)
    {
            if (folder.Name == "Folder Name")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.FullFolderPath);
                mailsFromThisFolder = folder;
            }
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (MAPIFolder subFolder in folder.Folders)
         {
              GetFolders(subFolder);
         }
    }
}

Outlook.Items items = mailsFromThisFolder.Items;
foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in items)
{
    //do someting
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to loop through subfolders. Folders.Item takes either an integer index (1 through Count) or the subfolder name

Comment: I got below error when i tried "foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in items) " 

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Logon must come before you do anything else.
2. Use something like the following

   oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
   oSubfolder = oFolder.Folders.Item("wolfy-server");