# Check Unread mail from outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook-2007

How to check unread mail of outlook 2007 from asp.net 4.0 ?
I am using Express edition and I have added reference of Microsoft office object library 12. I am not sure what should I code to see the uread mail from my outlook.
Any help?

**EDIT 1**

I have got the duplicate question on stackoverflow [Get unread Mails from Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055811/get-unread-mails-from-outlook)

But I am getting error while running the application [Runtime Error]:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Office, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What About Giving the following code a try

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; //you need to add the Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library to use this. mine is version 11 you might have an older or later version.

```
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
                Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi");

                object _missing = Type.Missing;
                ns.Logon(_missing, _missing, false, true);


                Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

                int unread = inbox.UnReadItemCount;

                foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in inbox.Items)
                {
                    string s = mail.Subject;
                }
```