# Auto Save Outlook Emails to folder using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

Based on Search Performed in Outlook i want to save the results into local drive 
How can i proceed ?
Is there any way in C# or ASP.Net to implement it ?
Many Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055811/get-unread-mails-from-outlook

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try this..
Please Let me know if there is any add-on in outlook to implement the same

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own Outlook plugin which does the job.

Start Visual Studio, create a new Outlook add-in. Depending your Visual Studio and Office version, maybe you have to install VS Tools for Office Runtime (if I remember correctly).

At startup register a handler for Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay and in the event handler add a new menu entry let's say "Save messages to disk" plus create an event handler which gets the selected messages and saves it to somewhere.

Something like this:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

private void MyAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Office.CommandBarButton bts = (Office.CommandBarButton)CommandBar.Controls.Add();
    bts.Visible = true;
    bts.Caption = "Save selected messages to disk";
    bts.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(bts_Click);
}

private void bts_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    Outlook.Selection list = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

    string fileName = "";

    Object selObject;
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[i];

        if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            mailItem = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);

            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
                mailItem.SaveAs(fileName, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does not have any error-checking, no optimization and this saves the messages to a temp file but you can get the basics.

It's also not auto-save, but you have to select the messages, rightclick and select the new menu item.