# How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I send email through Outlook using VB.Net 2005; this is working fine. 
At the same time, however, I receive the following message:

**A program is trying to automatically send Email on your behalf.

Do you want to allow this ?

if this is enexpected, it may be virus and you should choose no.**

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: this is desirable behaviour. The user *should* be warned of that kind of use of their personal data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "by design".  It's done to prevent viruses from doing things like going through the address book and automatically sending emails on the user's behalf.  Having the dialog prevents a virus from **silently** becoming a spam bot.

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't answering your direct question, but is there a reason you can use the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class and send using that? Or is this because you want the e-mail to show up in their sent items?

Comment: This is the same approach I had to take to prevent needing user interaction from an automated email signaling when certain processes failed etc.

Comment: From the comment above, if a copy is required in an inbox, the current user can be added to the recipient list.

Answer (score 4):

You need some library like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) to circumvent this popup. It's the default built-in security behaviour of Outlook (since version 2002 I think).

Comment: I keep seeing this reply, but I'm unsure if it's legit or not. I am cautious about infecting local machine. I assume it's legit if it continues to be posted on SE.