# VB6 MSOUTL.OLB Send Mail

Tags: vb6, outlook

I am using the MSOUTL.OLB library to send mails.

The code used is the following:

```
Public Sub SendErrorLogToMailRecipients()
    Dim errorReportText As String

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim txtStrm As TextStream

Set txtStrm = fso.OpenTextFile(frmMain.LogFileLocationFromRBT, ForReading, False, TristateTrue)
errorReportText = txtStrm.ReadAll
Call txtStrm.Close

If clsCom.IsStringEmpty(gstrErrorMailRecipients) Or clsCom.IsStringEmpty(errorReportText) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim mItm As MailItem
On Error GoTo EH
Set mItm = outlApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mItm.Save

With mItm
.To = gstrErrorMailRecipients
.Subject = "[[Express Claim Mail Process Error]]"
.Body = errorReportText
.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
.Send
End With

Exit Sub
EH:
    Call frmMain.LogErrorAcrossUsingRBT("SendErrorLogToMailRecipients")
End Sub
```

The issue us that I am receiving the following message in Outlook that is preventing me from sending the mail:

A program is trying to automaticly send e-mail on your behalf.
Do you want to allow this?
If this is unexpected, it may be a virus and you should choose "No".

I received a similar error when accessing the Mailbox through the API. My workaround was using [ClickYes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/). The problem is that I don't want to use the Pro version.

Thanks.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically

Comment: An OLB is not a library, just type/interface information.  You're using Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Outlook Redemption](http://msexchangetips.blogspot.com/2006/08/using-outlook-redemption-to-by-pass.html) may be useful to you.