# Disable Outlook Security Message Box

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I am developing outlook 2007 add in, and facing problems with **Outlook Security MessageBoxes**.
I know that i can disable it from the trust center and set allow programmatic access to true,
but i want to disable it by code.

**How can i disable Outlook Security MessageBox by code?**

*Note:* I am using C# and VSTO.

Comment: I don't think you can do it.. Without user's intervention

Comment: I've seen a lot of programs that disable this annoying message Boxes.
below is one of these: http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/outlook-security-manager-automate.php 

How do they did it?

Comment: Did you check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically

Comment: Thanks Shoban, this post is very helpful
Redemption library is exactly what i need. Do you know if there is a FREE library like redemtion?

Comment: Gaby, When exacly are you seeing the prompt ? can you post some code. Certin Properties are restricted and cause prompts. As TFD and Shoban says you can use 3rd party libs to chat MAPI directly to your store and get the info that you need but it all depends on what you are doing.

Comment: I am getting the prompt when i try to access mail information like from,to,cc..

Comment: yes the prompt will fire when you want to access email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

The security guard pops up when you try to access certain properties of the mail mainly around the email addresses. You can use [mapilib](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/security/) to stop it or use [redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)'s safe mail item. or

You can use the mail items [PropertyAccessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175514.aspx) to gain access to the underlying Mapi properties

For the "TO" you need PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS (or PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)

```
mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3003001F");
```

I would suggest that you download Dimitry's [Outlook spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) its "the" tool if you are developing Mapi/outlook etc.

You can then look up the Mapi properties and their ids  to get the others