# Outlook Automation - Security Warnings

Tags: c#, security, office-interop

I know this is a duplicate of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically), but it was asked over a year ago. Things changed and maybe there is "a real answer" nowerdays - so here it comes;
How to avoid those security warnings, when using autolook automation when sending mails (using outlook 2007+)?

Regards

**EDIT:**
I checked the Trust Center, it tells me that my Anti-Virus is valid and the setting for security is set to "alert me when my anti virus is out of date". But i keep getting those annoying Popups.

Further i have to add that it already used to run without the messagebox, but after i added/modified some profiles the popups began. I did *NOT* change any code! Any ideas?

A 3rd Party component is an option, but i would like to avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook 2007, go to Tools > Trust Center > Programmatic Access and select "Never" to turn off the prompt.

Comment: That sounds great. I seem not to have access to this setting (no idea why). The comboboxes are grayed out, but i can see that the setting is "...alert me when my anti-virus sw is out of date...", some lines below there is a line telling me that the state of my anti virus is "valid" - any ideas?

Comment: It can be disabled for several reasons. Check manually that there are no Windows updates or Antivirus updates to install. This option can also be disabled at the exchange server level, so you may have to go with a 3rd party solution.

Comment: I had the same problem with the grayed out comboboxes.  I was able to change them if I ran outlook as an admin.  This page also includes instructions on how to update it via the registry. http://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely ways around the problem by going at a lower level that the traditional COM Automation API for MSO. These guys do the work for you: http://www.add-in-express.com/

Comment: Unfortunately their code is like 200 lines of Delphi but they only sell a binary  DCU (equivalent to C 'OBJ' version).

Answer (score 2):

Worth a check: [Outlook Send E-mail Without Security Warning](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning)

Answer (score 1):

Still need [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CDO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526861.aspx) for it. and you can check [outlookcode](http://www.outlookcode.com/) for your problem.

**Edit:**
As @mz224, said you can disable it in 2007, but if you want install in computers is not good to do this, In all I have a big challenge on it, three years ago, I didn't find any good way for 2003, and 2007 was new, see this **[article](http://outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52)**, there was too many problem with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, Since 2007 outlook redesigned, and `Object model` added, many things became easier but In 2007 I didn't test above solution.

Comment: CDO is not an option, since i need to do some outlook specific stuff.

Comment: @Jaster, CDO is for Microsoft not third party

Comment: Its about full automation - kind of middleware solution.