# Can I make my fortran code e-mail me or text me once the code is run?

Tags: windows, email, fortran, sms

Well, the title says it all. I have a fortran code, and right before the last line of the code is excecuted I would like to get a notice in my mobile phone.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is certainly no such capability in the Fortran language, but you can use the system's capabilities and call something like https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows :). Can't fortran send an email through outlook for example?

Comment: Not directly, there are no email capabilities in the language. Youbmust find out how to send an email from any language and then adapt the solution to Fortran.

Comment: As others wrote, do this outside of Fortran.  You can use  the `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` intrinsic of Fortran to invoke the non-Fortran solution.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433202/sending-email-from-command-line-via-outlook-without-having-to-click-send