# stop warning of outlook when sending mail from python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am able to send email using following code :

```
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "My Subject"
newMail.Body = "My Body"
newMail.To  = "Example@gmail.com"
newMail.send()
```

But when It sends email, a warning is generated by outlook "A program is trying to send Email..."
How to disable such kind of warnings ? Please help..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You see a standard Outlook security prompt. There are few possible ways to avoid or supress the security dialog:

1. Use the low-level API for sending emails - Extended MAPI (Messaging API). You may consider Outlook as a big wrapper around that API.
2. Use any third-party wrapper around the low-level API described in #1.
3. Use the [Outlook security manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/) component (commercial) designed and developed exactly for supressing such warnings.

It is up to you which way is to choose. Read more about possible workarounds in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) page.