# Sending an Email with outlook with out user knowing

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am looking for a way to send an email in c# through outlook.interop without any popups or security warnings. I am using this code to get a trusted application object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869819.aspx ...

```
private void EmailMessage(string recipient, string subject, string body)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = GetApplication();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        try
        {
            email.Subject = subject;
            email.Body = body;
            email.To = recipient;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)email).Send();
            _emailConfirmation = true;
        }

        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {                
            _emailConfirmation = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            _emailConfirmation = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            //release the objects used to send email after message has been sent\\
            if (email != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(email);
            if (application != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }
    }
```

And this code to send the email, however it is still prompts the user because of the outlook security manager. Any ideas for a fix so that the user won't have any interruption or interaction with outlook?

Comment: I am guessing that Microsoft made it so that this is impossible on purpose.?

Comment: _"Sending an Email with outlook **with out user knowing**...however it is still prompts the user because of the **outlook security manager**. Any ideas for a fix so that the user won't have any interruption or interaction with outlook"_ - that sounds very **naughty**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.
Essentially you can.

1. Run your code on a machine with an up-top-date antivirus utility. Outlook will not display security prompts.
2. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or an Extended MAPI wrapper such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) that wraps Extended MAPI and is accessible from any language.