# Send Email via Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, email

I am using C# to send email via Outlook (unfortunately, I do not have an SMTP server I can use to send email, nor am I able to send it via SQL Server email because we are not a development team, so the company does not allow us to use these, and this is the only method I can think of to bypass those restrictions).

Technically, the code works, but when it runs, a message box appears [image: See Screenshot](see screenshot) that states "A program is trying to send an email message on your behalf.  If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date."  Is there something I can do in the code to suppress this message?

I clicked on the "Help" button as instructed from the screenshot and followed the instructions (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-email-address-information-or-sending-email-on-my-behalf-86cc5ece-379e-45e3-b8eb-3fefba09946b?ns=outlook&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zol900&helpid=olmain11.chm553714172&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) but I am not able to change the Programmatic Access section mentioned in the help article.

Here is the code I am using (it technically works if I click the Allow button on the popup):

```
public static bool SendMailWithOutlook(string subject, string htmlBody, string recipients, string[] 
     filePaths, MailSendType sendType)
        {
            try
            {
                // create the outlook application.
                Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
                if (outlookApp == null)
                    return false;

                // create a new mail item.
                Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                // set html body. 
                // add the body of the email
                mail.HTMLBody = htmlBody;

                //Add attachments.
                if (filePaths != null)
                {
                    foreach (string file in filePaths)
                    {
                        //attach the file
                        Outlook.Attachment oAttach = mail.Attachments.Add(file);
                    }
                }

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.To = recipients;

                if (sendType == MailSendType.SendDirect)
                    mail.Send();
                else if (sendType == MailSendType.ShowModal)
                    mail.Display(true);
                else if (sendType == MailSendType.ShowModeless)
                    mail.Display(false);

                mail = null;
                outlookApp = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need an SMTP Server to send Email!!!  It can be any email server you have an account.  I need to know more about the email accounts you have.  What server is your Outlook account using?  Is is local or a POP account?  Are you on a Corporate Network?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183034/how-to-handle-security-pop-up-in-outlook-using-c-sharp

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223101/outlook-email-to-pdf-security-prompt

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291433/sending-an-email-with-outlook-with-out-user-knowing

Comment: I appreciate the comments and help, but unfortunately I cannot interface with our company's SMTP server via code due to restrictions, corporate policy, etc.  The only email I have access to is Outlook via my desktop.  I also cannot access web mail of any kind due to company restrictions that we are not allowed to access any outside mail accounts on the company's network (they are blocked).  I am also not able to change Outlook security settings via group policy.  It sounds like there isn't many options then to eliminate this error unless I can code directly to the Outlook server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)