# Outlook email to pdf security prompt

Tags: c#, email, pdf, outlook, office-interop

I have a task which i need to create a program that converts outlook email to pdf.

this is my code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores["Blah"].GetRootFolder();

                List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();
                Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;
                foreach (Folder folder in subFolders)
                {
                    if (folder.Name == "Inbox")
                    {
                        Items items = folder.Items;
                        foreach (object item in items)
                        {
                            if (item is MailItem)
                            {
                                MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;
                                string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "New folder", mailItem.EntryID + mailItem.SenderName.Replace("/", "") + ".msg");
                                mailItem.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

the code is working but the outlook contains thousands of email. The outlook prompt a message every 10 minutes similar to the screenshot below

[image]

is there a way to avoid getting the message? Programatically or a setting will do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's not related to the programming instead of it's related the outlook security settings.

For every version of outlook you can find the settings for this pop-up just follow the instruction on [this blog](http://www.ryadel.com/en/how-to-stop-the-outlook-a-program-is-trying-to-access-pop-up/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a setting in your out look.

**Mine is outlook 2013.**

`File->options :` a window opens

In the window select `Trust Center`

You can see a button `Trust center Settings`

Options in window changes. `Select Programmatic access`

UnCheck the radio button `Never warn me about suspicious activity (not recommended)`

**Through program, you can change below registry settings:**

Go to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\outlook\security"

Change below settings programatically:

```
PromptSimpleMAPISend  -- 2
PromptSimpleMAPINameResolve -- 2
PromptSimpleMAPIOpenMessage -- 2
```

By default when outlook is installed, the above values comes with zero value. What I do in my program is, I turn them to "2" programatically just before sending the email and turn them back to zero later point of time.