# How to handle security pop-up in outlook using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, automation

While Automating Outlook using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook a security pop-u is  getting displayed saying "A program is trying to access a email folders.......".

Please help how can we bypass/solve using C# without using 'Redemption' or by changing the security settings(do not have access).

P.S: could we use JavaScript executer to accept the alert box?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook.

There are several ways for suppressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, Redemption.
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object. And then communicate from a standalone application with an add-in using standard .Net tools (Remoting).
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.

You can read more about all these ways on the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) page.