# Disable warning about a program trying to send an email

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I send an email using Outlook 2010 with Access VBA.

I get a warning from Microsoft Outlook about a program trying to send an email and I'm forced to push allow.

I have the Microsoft Outlook Object Library 14 from the reference in VBA.

In Outlook - Options - access through programin is marked on don't show warnings.

I added the next entries in regedit

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\ 
<version>\Outlook\Security
Value name: AdminSecurityMode
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 3

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\ 
<version>\Outlook\Security
Value name: PromptOOMSend
Value name: PromptOOMAddressBookAccess
Value name: PromptOOMAddressInformationAccess
Value name: PromptOOMMeetingTaskRequestResponse
Value name: PromptOOMSaveAs
Value name: PromptOOMFormulaAccess
Value name: PromptSimpleMAPISend
Value name: PromptSimpleMAPINameResolve
Value name: PromptSimpleMAPIOpenMessage
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 2
```

I also add DoCmd.SetWarnings False in the email function.

How to disable this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning appears for using DoCmd.sendObject to send an email, so instead of downloading thir party components.

I just not used doCmd.sendObjects and used a function like this:

```
 Public Function CreateNewMessage()
 Dim objMsg As MailItem

 Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMsg
.To = "Alias@domain.com"
.CC= "Alias2@domain.com"
.BCC = "Alias3@domain.com"
.Subject = "This is the subject"
.Categories = "Test"
.VotingOptions = "Yes;No;Maybe;"
.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
.Importance = olImportanceHigh
.Sensitivity = olConfidential
.Attachments.Add ("path-to-file.docx")

' Calculate a date using DateAdd or enter an explicit date
.ExpiryTime = DateAdd("m", 6, Now) '6 months from now
.DeferredDeliveryTime = #8/1/2012 6:00:00 PM#

.Display
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Function
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

The common way to solve this is to install and use [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) .

Another method is to bypass Outlook completely and send via *SMTP*, but that is another story and requires a lot more code.

Answer (score 1):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook.

There are several ways for supressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for supressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, Redemption.
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object.
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how i develop a COM add-in to make this possible?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019