# Getting POP up message while accessing email though VB Script

Tags: outlook, automation, automationanywhere

I am trying to read the mail through VBscript or Automation Anywhere script. I am getting a popup message 
"A Program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in outlook. If it is unexpected, click deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date"

[image]

POP up message while reading email through script or Automation Anywhere.

I have tried the solution from Trust Center. But Message is displaying "This feature is not supported in this version.

I have gone through the registry setting option but the path is not found. I am using O365.

So let me know the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook.

There are several ways for suppressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/).
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object. And then communicate from a standalone application with an add-in using standard .Net tools (Remoting).
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.

Answer (score 0):

It's Office 365 and running on exchange protocol which is not supported by AA Client, and that why you are trying to do it using VBS.

The solution to this issue would be using [Automation Anywhere Outlook Metabot](https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/perform-various-email-operations/). This metabot can integrate with the Outlook App and do a lot of function on email, meeting, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in AA, but I have tried to do this in G1ANT.
It was quite simple there, you have to use the argument ""ignorecertificateerrors"" with setting its value as true.

```
♥yesterday = ⟦date:dd.MM.yyyy⟧13.01.2019
mail.imap imap.gmail.com login mail@gmail.com password     p@$$w0rD sincedate 
♥yesterday todate ♥date onlyunreadmessages true markallmessagesasread false 
ignorecertificateerrors true result ♥list 
foreach ♥element in ♥list
dialog ♥element
end
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script between Error handling commands.

After it fails just click on allow with an object cloning command. Should work this way

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script(Assuming it to be a .vbs file) using CMD

`cmd.exe /s /c start yourScript.vbs`

This will execute the script asynchronously and Automation Anywhere will be free to click on allow button. And yes, you need to type `cmd.exe` in the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue for most of the metabots users, You can refer *`ReadMe Perform various outlook operations.pdf`* file within this bots My Tasks folder. Refer Bot Store for more details: [Perform various outlook operations](https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/perform-various-email-operations/)

1. In Outlook, click File, and then click Options.
2. Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.
3. Click Programmatic Access.
4. Select the option that you prefer. If you want to stop these warning
   messages permanently, select the **Never warn me about suspicious
   activity (not recommended)** option.

**Note** If these options are not available, exit Outlook, and then start Outlook again in elevated mode. To do this, type Outlook on the desktop or in the Start Search box, right-click the Microsoft Outlook search result, click Properties, click the Compatibility tab, and then click ***Run this program as an administrator***.

5. Click OK two times.

Refer the https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i for more details with screenshots.