# Create and send outlook email

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I have been roaming forums and not finding any answer to my question.
all of the solution (and question) is about using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`;
for some reason **I am not allowed to use any** `office.interop`.

I even tried:

```
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sender@server.com");
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.From = fromAddress;
message.To.Add("receiver@theirServer.com");
message.CC.Add("receiver2@theirServer.com");
message.Subject = "theSubject";
message.Body = "TheBody";

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("zzz.server.xxx");
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@server.com", "password");

smtpClient.Send(message);
```

the code fail to authenticate the credential, even after I hard-coded the password, but I feel that there must be a better way.

Comment: I found this eventually helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489397/send-mail-using-my-outlook-account

Comment: @AlinaB. not allowed to use any `office.interop`

Comment: Is this winforms, web, WPF or what? Obviously its not VSTO yet you've tagged it Outlook, so what type of application do you need to send emails from?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to be desired of your question. Can you post the response from the server or the error you are receiving?

Here are some observations and feedback that may help you
Specify the port

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("zzz.server.xxx", PORTNUMBER);
```

Set some of the basic properties

```
smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false; //must be set prior to credentials
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
```

Set the message encoding

```
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Send Asyncronously and use a callback to determine the result

```
//add callback 
smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

//set token
string userToken = "tokenString";

//send asynchronously
smtpCient.SendAsync(message, userToken);

public static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
             String token = (string) e.UserState;

            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                 //do something if it was cancelled
            }
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
               MessageBox.Show( e.Error.ToString());
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message sent.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to add, you may need to Enable SSL using the EnableSsl property on the SmtpClient. [SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the credentials, including the format of the username through configuring the account in an alternative client, such as Outlook?

You might need:

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender", "password");
```

or

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("DOMAIN\sender", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your email server an Exchange Server? If so, you can use the Exchange Web Services (EWS) to send emails and save copies in the Sent Items folder. A simple example can be seen here:

[Send Exchange Email](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Send-Email-with-Exchange-50189e57)

[More Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/jj220501%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)