# Error while sending Outlook email using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like, within Excel, to send an email from a userform.

I created test code, according to Microsoft how to page.

When I try to use `.send` (email address swapped to dummy one for the purpose of the question)

> "application-defined or object-defined  error".

When I use `.display` the message shows up on the screen. I have added references for Outlook 16 and Office 16, as suggested in other solutions.

I wonder if it is an issue related to company policies.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim oListObj As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    email_to = "test.user@test.com"
    email_body = "test 123"
    email_subject = "Test email"
    
    With OutMail
        .To = email_to
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = email_subject
        .Body = email_body
        '.Display
        .Send ' THIS LINE IS CAUSING ERROR FOR ME
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?  I was able to run your code with no problems.

Comment: Codes works just fine to me. Which line cause the error? You may need to add reference `Microsoft Outlook Object Library x`.

Comment: .Send line is causing the error. I have also added the library mentioned.

Comment: No reference to the outlook library needed, since you're using late-binding to create the outlook object. Without being too sure, I'd say a) remove those empty strings in CC and BCC and b) check the security options in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The `Send` method of the `MailItem` class is a protected method in the Outlook object model which means it can throw security prompts in Outlook or just give errors when using an unsafe Outlook `Application` instance. It happens when you try to automate Outlook from external applications. You can find a similar thread which lists possible solutions, see [How to avoid the Outlook Security warning for email automation - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926605/how-to-avoid-the-outlook-security-warning-for-email-automation-vba).

There are several ways for suppressing security prompts/errors in the code:

1. Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, Redemption.
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted `Application` object.
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.

See [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings) for more information. Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf warning in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf)
- [How to Prevent the VBA Macro Security Warning in Microsoft Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa155754(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)