# Enable Outlook Popup "A program is trying to send an email ..."

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook-2007

I am looking to **enable** the following message:
[image: A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook.]

---

### Why?

Because some of my users are experiencing bugs when clicking on "Deny" ... And for some reason mine will never popup. I probably allowed access for ever? There is no code to prevent this pop up message because my users receive it.

Is it possible to re-enable this message by Outlook's UI? I tried looking in Options and Advanced options but I haven't found anything related to security messages. I have Outlook 2007.

Comment: Is it possible to insert the data into an EmailQueue table in your DB, and then have a separate service actually send the email not using the Outlook API?

Comment: @MikeCole Good question, I haven't tried it or infact ... I haven't even heard of doing that. I'm learning every day and will definately try out what you asked in the future.

Comment: Generally (IMO) you don't want client applications sending emails, especially not using Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click on the File tab
- Click Options
- Click Trust Center tab at the bottom in the Outlook Options window. And you can see Microsoft Outlook Trust Center pane displaying at the bottom of the body part.

[image: Trust Center]

Then I just went into the "Programmatic Access" to set the options accordingly.

[image]

http://www.addintools.com/documents/outlook/where-trust-center.html

Answer (score 0):

That security level can be circumvented entirely using C++.

However since C++ may not be your strong suit (and mine neither) I use "[Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm)" which is basically a very similar wrapper API built in C++ to access outlook API but without the security popups.

It is not very expensive Library ($249 re-distributable includes 32 and 64 bit versions) and has worked well for me.

Comment: I've seen the Outlook Redemption option when I was searching for the answer. I was finally able to find what I was looking for though. Thanks anyway!