# How to click on "Allow" button of an Outlook alert window using Python

Tags: python

I have written a code in Python to automatically send out customer reports through Outlook to different email addresses. My code is compiled to an executable file which I double click to send out the reports. However, sometimes I get this Outlook alert window - "A program is trying to send an e-mail on your behalf..." with "Allow", "Deny" and "Help" buttons. I am aware, this might be because the anti-virus signature might be outdated. However, I want to detect the presence of this alert window and auto-click the "Allow" button if present, through Python code without having to click on it manually every single time. Have already searched a lot for a solution but still searching. Please guide.

Comment: use nirsoft's GUIPropView with command line to detect the windows and button position, but I think using autohotkey to loop ifwinexist is much easy

Comment: Thank you kissson for your guidance. Will try it and come back. But my concern is, what if other users on the office floor (who also use my program) move the alert window  around ? will the correct coordinates of the "Allow" button sill be captured ? I am wondering if ctypes/sendkeys can be used to tackle this alert window.

Comment: autohotkey worked!! Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion!! Here's my trial working code :-

Comment: `from ahk import AHK`
`ahk = AHK()`
`npd_win = ahk.find_window(title=b'Untitled - Notepad')`
`if npd_win is not None:`
    `npd_win.activate()`
    `npd_win_text = npd_win.text`
    `if b'unexpected' in npd_win_text:`
        `tlc_x = list(npd_win.rect[0:1])`
        `tlc_y = list(npd_win.rect[1:2])`
        `tlc_x = tlc_x[0] + 825`
        `tlc_y = tlc_y[0] + 6`
        `ahk.mouse_position = (tlc_x, tlc_y)`
        `ahk.click()`
    `else: print('Notepad window found but does not contain "unexpected" string.')`
`else: print('Notepad window not found.')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)