# Send an e-mail through a macro and by pass security settings

Tags: ms-access

I am using Office 365 for MS Access and MS Outlook. I have a macro that, upon opening, fires off queries and attempts to e-mail the last query.

However, when I do, it prompts me with a dialog box that says:

```
A program is trying to send an email message on your behalf, If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date.

For more information about email safety and how you might be able to avoid getting this warning, click Help.

Allow    Deny    Help
```

So far, I've tried this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D8M3jo0a7U

Where you go into your MS Outlook settings and turn off warnings. However, it still gives me the same error.

Any ideas?

~~EDIT~~

Adding solution ideas as I attempt them. The following list are failures:

```
In Outlook: Trust Center -> Programmatic Access -> Disable all security
In MS Access: Trust Center -> Macro Settings -> Enable all macros
Run the registery edit to run system in Admin and try the query again.
```

Comment: I use Access 2010 and I don't get this message if my Windows anti-virus protection is current.

Comment: @June7 Anti-virus is up to date. Also, I added a third edit to what I tried, using regedit.

Comment: How are you sending the e-mail? I use `CDO.Message` to send e-mail from VBA to O365 with no problems.

Comment: I am using the EmailSendObject macro within Access. I will look into CDO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)

Answer (score 0):

The professional way to send emails via Access is to bypass Outlook and use either CDO or [vbSendmail](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=109)...

Comment: Ok, I've tried this for a while now and I continue to get this error: ```Run-time error '-2147220978 (8004020e); The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: Client was not authetnicated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM``` Deleted some details as I wasn't sure if something would indicate my particular server.

Comment: Do you have Exchange...you have to setup a receive connector to whitelist the IPs that try to send the email and get blocked.

Comment: I do indeed have Exchange. Will try this suggestion.