# How to handle Microsoft outlook app pop-ups using selenium when automating in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, outlook

I'm busy automating a process using selenium package in python. My process requires me to send emails using outlook app, but when I try sending emails from python using the code below:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'email_address'

mail.Subject = 'Email Subject'
mail.Body = 'Email Body'
attachment = 'Attachment'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
```

I get this pop-up from outlook:
[image]

Selenium only works for web-based automation, how can I solve this problem using python so that whenever I send an email it automatically clicks on Allow without having to do it manually.

I had a look at my Outlook 2016 Programmatic Access Settings and the Antivirus Status is Invalid:
[image]

Comment: Check out https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-email-address-information-or-sending-email-on-my-behalf-86cc5ece-379e-45e3-b8eb-3fefba09946b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a standard security prompt produced by Outlook when you access any secured property or just send an item. You can read more about that in the ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i) article.

There are several ways to avoid such prompts when you send emails:

1. Use the Outlook Security Manager which allows turning off and on security prompts at runtime. See [Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/outlook-security-manager-automate.php) for the sample code.
2. Use a low-level API that doesn't trigger security prompts - Extended MAPI or any other wrappers around that API such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/).
3. Develop a COM add-in that has access to the trusted *Application* object.
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines to not trigger security prompts.